# how to make requests on a QlikView site with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I came across a problem in extracting excel by varying some variables on a website that is QlikView.

Information:

```
=== Document Info =========================

Document Name          PORTALQVW/SISSER.qvw

Authenticated User                         

Client Platform              browser.chrome

=== QlikView Server Info ==================
```

Build Number            11.20.12904.0409.10

I would like to extract an excel on the site: http://indicadores.agricultura.gov.br/atlasdoseguro/index.htm

However, it is in the "Produtividade" tab where the "Estado", "Ano" and "Cultura" is selected.

Has anyone made requests on a site of this type to help me?